# IRS : Getting Error When Manually Setting Endpoint Address. "The WS Security Header in the message is invalid"

Tags: web-services, cxf, irs

IRS ACA has two web services, 1) to submit aca forms and 2) to check the status of submitted forms. The problem I face is on 2) one, i.e web service where we check status.

I use Java 1.8 and Apache CXF 3.1.5 as a client to these services.

The problem is when I set the endpoint address on the cxf client proxy manually, I get the security error and if I don't set, it uses the address from WSDL and that works fine.

Has anyone faced this problem ?

Comment: **RESOLVED** : It was my mistake. Both web services have different end point addresses and I was using the same endpoint address for both services.

Comment: hi, we are still not able to pass WS security, can you pls share some reference or code snippet of this?

Comment: You can refer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34959348/2577574